# Output PSComputerName in GWMI filter

Tags: powershell

I need to locate computers on the global network using WMI Class win32_NTDomain and the ClientSiteName value which has multiple listings per computer but most listings show the correct city. I can filter that but not also return each computer name matching the location

I have tried adding PSComputerName to the output selection to no avail

```
$Computers | %{Get-WMIObject -CN $_ Win32_NTDomain -ea 0 | select -expand clientsitename | group | sort count -desc | select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1}
```

What I need is output showing each computer name and its clientsitename. Like: PC01 London , PC02 Boston. Right now all it does is show the city. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PLEASE, fix your code formatting.

Comment: you are stripping out _everything except the `ClientSiteName` in  your `Select-Object` section. you need to NOT do that. [*grin*] it is rarely wise to strip out information unless you are CERTAIN that you will not need it - and you  need what you threw away.

Comment: Its just a one-liner though, not stripping anything out

Comment: @IanB - if you want to send a reply to a comment you need to start it with `@username` - otherwise it just sits there & only gets seen by accident. [*grin*]

Comment: @IanB - this section of your pipeline >>> `select -expand clientsitenam` <<< strips out everything _except_ the things listed ... and you only list one item.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ok, lets break it down using one computer:  PC01 | %{Get-WMIObject -CN $_ Win32_NTDomain | select -expand clientsitename | group | sort count -desc | select Name -First 1} .   So PC01 is inerrant in the command but I cannot see how to produce it again in the output.  All that does is name the ClientSiteName but I want to add the PC name as well.

Comment: @IanB - this >>> `select -expand clientsitename` <<< leaves ONLY that one property. you also want the system name - and that does not seem to exist at all in the output of you WMI call. so ... you need to add it via a calculated property combined with something like `-PipelineVariable` in your 1st or 2nd pipeline stage to get the system name into your output object.

Comment: ok thanks @Lee_Dailey , I will research -PipelineVariable and calculated properties

Comment: @Lee_Dailey see my solution below. :-)

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it without calculated properties:

```
 ***$Computers | %{icm -cn $_ -EA 0 {GWMI Win32_NTDomain | Select -Expand clientsitename | group | sort count -desc | select -First 1} | Select Name, PSComputerName}***
```

I used `Invoke-Command` instead.

Thanks all.

Comment: yep, `Invoke-Command` includes the target system name in its added properties ... glad you found a working solution! [*grin*]